# a simple pointer code

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int* a;
    *a=20;
    printf("%i\n",*a);

    return 0;
}
```

I have the code above. when the code in runtime, I always get the error message "filename.exe has stop working". Why?

Comment: Uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not allocate any memory for the pointer to point at. You can do so like this:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
```

or like this:

```
int value;
int *a = &value;
```

If you allocate with `malloc` then you'll want to call `free` on the pointer when you are finished using it.

Accessing an uninitialized pointer leads to undefined behaviour. In your program it led to segmentation fault, one very common outcome of uninitialized pointer access.

Comment: My understanding is after free, `a` is now dangling pointer which probably having a address but not pointing to any valid memory location. So it is a good practice to set it as NULL

Comment: @Vivek27 It depends. If the pointer is local and you are about to return from the function, why bother? If the variable remains in scope for a long time, then your function is probably badly factored.

Answer (score 1):

In `int* a;`   `a`'s default value is garbage, and points to an invalid memory, you can't assign to that. And assignment like `*a=20;` this is causes an undefined behavior at run time. (syntax wise code is correct so compiled) you may some time get a seg-fault too.

either do:

```
int i;
int *a = &i;  // a points to a valid memory that is i
*a = 20;
```

or with dynamic memory allocation using calloc() or malloc() functions.

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = 20;
```

Remember dynamic allocated memories we have to deallocate (free)  explicitly when we have done with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have `wild pointer`, either assign memory to it using `malloc`

```
int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

or use a stack variable

```
int b = 0;
int *a = &b;
*a=20;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your assignment 
*a = 20.

You can't allocate a value to a pointer variable like that.

int b = 20;
a = &b;

Thanks,
Santhosh